# How to create a modular app in Android

Tags: android

I would like to create a modular app in Android. A user would download the core app with some basic functionality, then later on download more more modules and install them into the app. He will also be able to uninstall them, but still have the core app. Is this possible in Android? How should I approach it?

Comment: Have a suite of apps, with one app designated as the core app, and with IPC (e.g., AIDL, broadcasts, `ContentProvider`) for the communications between those apps.